# Java: how to use a loop to create a string without printing?

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner with java and one concept is rather unclear to me. I need to create a method that creates a new string by replicating another string. For example, if the String1 is "java" and it is specified that it needs to be repeated 4 times and each of them needs to be separated with a comma, the new string would look like this: java, java, java, java

However, the method should not print it, but only create a new string that is then printed in the main program. This is a problem for me, because I have trouble understanding, how can I use a loop to create something without printing it. I think that the following code would print it correctly:

```
public static void replicate(String str, int times) {
   for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      System.out.print(str);
      if (i < times -1) {
         System.out.print(", ");
      }
   }
}
```

How could I transform it so that I could use the method to create a new string without printing it? I am assuming this is something super simple, but I just don't know at all how to do this, because every guide just uses examples of printing in these kinds of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should be useful for academic purposes in which you cannot use all of Java's libraries. You want to use a variable to store the repeated text and then return that variable to the main method for it to be printed. For non academic purposes or in cases when efficiency is a priority the [java.lang.StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object should be used.

```
 public static String replicate(String str, int times) {
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        newString = newString + str;
        if(i<times-1){
            newString = newString + ", ";
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is much better with Collections and join

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        String newstr=String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(3, "java"));
        System.out.println(newstr);
    }
}
```

Working fiddle-https://repl.it/repls/OfficialInvolvedObject

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do using the [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class, which can be used like this:

```
public static String replicate(String str, int times) {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      builder.append(str);
      if (i < times - 1) {
         builder.append(", ");
      }
   }

   return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a `StringBuilder`, as exemplified by [Emily's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59018821/6395627). Since the same delimiter is used each time another option is to use [`java.util.StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html). Here's an example:

```java
public static String replicate(String str, int times) {
  StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
  for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    joiner.add(str);
  }
  return joiner.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming this is something super simple

You are right. While the other answers show various helper classes, you can do it with re-assigning a single `String` variable already:

```
public static String replicate(String str, int times) {
   String result="";
   for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      result += str; //System.out.print(str);
      if (i < times -1) {
         result += ", "; //System.out.print(", ");
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Or, if you do not worry about having to provide `0` copies:

```
public static String replicate(String str, int times) {
   String result=str; // one copy, without comma
   for (int i = 1; i < times; i++) {
      result += ", " + str; // all the other copies have their commas
   }
   return result;
}
```

This latter "trick" can be used with `StringBuilder` too of course:

```
public static String replicate(String str, int times) {
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str);
   for (int i = 1; i < times; i++) {
      result.append(", ");
      result.append(str);
   }
   return result.toString();
}
```

Btw, it may be worth mentioning what there story about `StringBuilder` is: when Java sees `something=string1+string2`, internally it writes `StringBuilder temp=new StringBuilder(string1); temp.append(string2); something=temp.toString()` (of course it is an unnamed, internal variable, not "temp"). So a brand new `StringBuilder` object is created, appended, converted back to a brand new `String` and thrown away every time. That is why the suggested method is to have one, dedicated `StringBuilder`, use it many times, and get the result from it only once, at the end.